# Can a single SQL Server instance issue the same SYSDATETIME twice?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index, timestamp

I am contemplating using a `datetime2(7)` as a clustered index.

If I were to always populate that column using `SYSDATETIME` is it possible for the same instance to issue the same value twice (assuming we don't do something like set the system clock back)?

Alternatively, what is a cohesive strategy for ensuring uniqueness on such a column, even if it that comes at a cost of time precision?

For my use, I really only care about the seconds, but I will be doing a lot of range queries on this column so the CI *seems* appropriate.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10104128/565869.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The resolution of the Windows clock is decent, but not perfect. You should use another field, such as an `INT IDENTITY`, to ensure uniqueness.  But go ahead and cluster on the date *first*, if it suits your needs.

Alternatively, you could use a `DATETIME` PK, but supervise inserts with a stored procedure that verifies the uniqueness of the incoming date, and pauses if necessary.  I can whip up an example if you'd like.

Edit:

Another option, borrowing from ypercube's comment, would be a non-unique clustered index on the date field, and a unique non-clustered primary key on the `ID` field. This would keep your other indices smaller, as they would point to the narrow `ID` column, but would also entail two hops to get to actual data.

Comment: You can also cluster on the datetime only (and nothing else) without having it unique. Since the accuracy is milliseconds, if it rarely has duplicates, the CI will be not much wider than a DATETIME index.

Comment: I could easily cluster on a smaller `datetime2` I was concerned about the **possibility** of duplicates in the CI. Of course I know I can CI on an `INT` ... but that data will never be range-searched in my use case... which is the entire point of the question :D

Comment: @ypercube: You could, and the system would create a hidden "uniquifier."  Personally, I'd rather have it handled in the foreground, so to speak, but the width would be the same (four bytes), so YMMV.

Comment: I thought the uniquifier was appended only for the rows that have duplicate value in the rest of the CI. I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm no expert, I've never had occasion to use one, but I would assume that the field has to exist regardless, so the system has a place to put a value if a duplicate ever appears.  Sounds like a good separate question!

Comment: I am pretty certain @ypercube is correct that the identifier is not created until there is a duplicate. My point with this question is that I *never* want a duplicate. Even if that means my timestamp isn't really accurate...

Comment: If I cluster on the datetime *and* the auto-number then my range queries will use the CI. (The data will, coincidentally, also by physically ordered be the auto-number) but I need to add a separate, stand-alone index to that PK column.... Is that your suggestion?

Comment: My first suggestion is a single PK on { Date, ID }.  Alternatively, you could cluster on { Date, ID } but put the non-clustered PK on { ID }.  This would give you a narrower PK, which is important if you'll have lots of additional indices.  Unless that's the case, I'd recommend the simpler option: a single clustered PK.  As @ypercube says, you could even omit the explicit ID field and let the server handle uniquifying behind the curtain.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful choosing your clustered index KEY because it will be propagated to all non clustered indexes of your table. Datetime2 values are 8 bytes length, you may consider an `INT IDENTITY` like Jon said.

Comment: I actually recommend using both, in a compound key.  Clustering is very efficient for range filters, which are common for dates; the ID field would serve to disambiguate in the case the OP is asking about: where two records are created with the same date/time.